# Проблема с установкой lwjgl с помощью maven

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven, lwjgl

Битый час пытаюсь запустить окошко, но постоянно с ошибкой. Пытаюсь запустить [этот](https://www.lwjgl.org/guide) код.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>     at org.lwjgl.system.Pointer$Default.(Pointer.java:67)
>     at org.lwjgl.system.Callback.(Callback.java:41)
>     at me.adbol.game.MainC.init(MainC.java:38)
>     at me.adbol.game.MainC.run(MainC.java:23)
>     at me.adbol.game.MainC.main(MainC.java:113)
>
> Caused by:
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   org.lwjgl.system.jni.JNINativeInterface.nNewDirectByteBuffer(JJ)Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;
>   at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.(MemoryUtil.java:133)
>     ... 5 more 
>   Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   org.lwjgl.system.jni.JNINativeInterface.nNewDirectByteBuffer(JJ)Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;
>     at org.lwjgl.system.jni.JNINativeInterface.nNewDirectByteBuffer(Native
>   Method)
>   at org.lwjgl.system.jni.JNINativeInterface.NewDirectByteBuffer(JNINativeInterface.java:1104)
>     at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.getMarkOffset(MemoryUtil.java:2895)
>     at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.(MemoryUtil.java:113)
>   ... 5 more

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>me.adbol.game</groupId>
<artifactId>Game</artifactId>
<version>0.1</version>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.mavennatives</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-nativedependencies-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpacknatives</id>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>mavenNatives</id>
        <name>Maven Natives Repository</name>
        <url>http://mavennatives.googlecode.com/svn/repo</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
        <artifactId>lwjgl</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
        <artifactId>lwjgl-platform</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0b</version>
        <classifier>natives-windows</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
        <artifactId>lwjgl-glfw</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
        <artifactId>lwjgl-opengl</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>java3d</groupId>
        <artifactId>vecmath</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Содержимое target/natives:

```
glfw.dll
glfw32.dll
jemalloc.dll
jemalloc32.dll
lwjgl.dll
lwjgl32.dll
OpenAL.dll
OpenAL32.dll
```

В VM-optiions прописано: -Djava.library.path=target\natives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил проблему, просто воспользовавшись [генератором](https://www.lwjgl.org/customize) с официального сайта.

На случай, если ссылка не будет работать - необходимый функционал, включающий OpenGL:

```
<properties>
    <lwjgl.version>3.2.3</lwjgl.version>
    <lwjgl.natives>natives-windows</lwjgl.natives>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
            <artifactId>lwjgl-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${lwjgl.version}</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
        <artifactId>lwjgl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
        <artifactId>lwjgl-assimp</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
        <artifactId>lwjgl-glfw</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
        <artifactId>lwjgl-openal</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
        <artifactId>lwjgl-opengl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
        <artifactId>lwjgl-stb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
        <artifactId>lwjgl</artifactId>
        <classifier>${lwjgl.natives}</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
        <artifactId>lwjgl-assimp</artifactId>
        <classifier>${lwjgl.natives}</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
        <artifactId>lwjgl-glfw</artifactId>
        <classifier>${lwjgl.natives}</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
        <artifactId>lwjgl-openal</artifactId>
        <classifier>${lwjgl.natives}</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
        <artifactId>lwjgl-opengl</artifactId>
        <classifier>${lwjgl.natives}</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
        <artifactId>lwjgl-stb</artifactId>
        <classifier>${lwjgl.natives}</classifier>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```